# How to fix my code?

Tags: c, trigonometry

Taylor series expansion of cos(x) with a given accuracy

**eps**
**Recursive approach**

> [Error] overloaded function with no contextual type information

How can I fix this error?

[Photo1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEKpc.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double cos(double x, double eps, double s=0,double n=0,double a=0) {
    if (abs(n)<1){
    cos=cos(x, eps,1,1,1);
}
else {
    a = -a*x*x / ((2*n-1) * (2*n));
    if (abs(a)<=eps) {
        cos=s;
    }
    else{
        cos=cos(x, eps, s+a, a,n+1);
    }
  }
} 
int main () {
    double x;
    scanf("%f", &x);
    cos(x, 0.000000000000001);
}
```

Comment: Function `cos` is declared to return a double-value.  However I do not see any `return` statement in that function.

Comment: Also C doesn't support default arguments

Comment: Meh, C is not pascal! Use `return s;` instead of `cos=s;` and so on.

Comment: Your error message seems to be a C++ error message. Are you compiling as C or C++?

Comment: As @crashmstr points out, C doesn't have overloading, so a C compiler wouldn't complain about an overloaded function. Make sure that your source file is named with a `.c` suffix, and that you're compiling it using a C compiler, not a C++ compiler. And your indentation is inconsistent; the `else` should be aligned under the `if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You included `math.h`, which has a function named `cos`, that works a bit differently.

You have overloaded that name (eg. written another function also with the name `cos`) but have not given the compiler any means to deduce which version of `cos` you want to call.

Fix this by naming your function something different and unique.

---

Here's my attempt at a fix:

```
double TaylorCOS(double x, double eps, double s=0,double n=0,double a=0)
{
    if (abs(n)<1)
    {
        return TaylorCOS(x, eps,1,1,1);
    }

    a = -a*x*x / ((2*n-1) * (2*n));
    if (abs(a)<=eps)
    {
        return s;
    }

    return TaylorCOS(x, eps, s+a, a,n+1);
}
```

Comment: Also, OP shall fix `return` statements. Now he is trying to use pascal syntax `FunctionName = value;` instead of `return value;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign to a function identifier like you do in

```
cos=s;
cos=cos(x, eps, s+a, a,n+1);
```

Neither in C, nor in C++. This program is broken beyond repair.